# Convert Base64 String to an Image File and Save it to File System?

Tags: c#, .net, image, console-application

I am trying to make a .Net 6 console application that would take in a base64string and then save it to the file system as an actual image file

Example

I have this image

https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/28/12/35/cat-1285634_960_720.png

I would have this image already as a base64 string.

Now I want to save to my file system as "cat-1285634_960_720.png"

I just can't figure out how to do it. All the examples I see say to use Image.Save() but I can't find that in .Net6 and looks like it is removed.

Comment: Convert the Base64 string first into a byte array, then write the byte array into the target file. Bon appetite! But considering that you already have written many answers under the `asp.net` and other tags related to C# (according to your profile), i tend to suspect you know this already with your question missing some pertinent info regarding the real obstacle you are facing.

Comment: _I ... have this image ... as a base64 string._ So the original .png file was converted to a base64 string? So just decode it and write to disk. The `Image` class shouldn't be needed. The file type shouldn't matter at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First convert the base64 string to a byte array and then use File.WriteAllBytes(...) to save it:

```
byte[] imageByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

File.WriteAllBytes("image.png", imageByteArray);
```

Comment: Thanks this confirms that I was doing it right, but had a problem with my base64 string.